# Git diff origin/master..master does not show in difference but there are difference

Tags: github

I have pushed my project to github, but not all folders are committed to github.
Even if I do git origin/master..master it does not show any difference but there are difference as many folders are not committed to github.
Anything what I am doing wrong while git push -u origin master
How do I correct the situation[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KGNNE.jpg)
PFA..

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XQils.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`git diff` shows the difference between two repository's commits. If you have other files (git doesn't care about folders) then ensure they're committed:

```
git add . 
git commit -m "something meaningful" 
git diff origin/master..master
```

If on `git add .` you see some files are not tracked that should be, adjust your `.gitignore` file in the local directory.

Comment: Thanks mjb for clearing the doubt..I removed the entries from .gitignore and added and committed and was able to upload the missed files and folders in github ..Thanks again

Comment: Great sromit - please check that my answer addressed your question when you get a chance.